# Redis pub/sub with multiple node instances

Tags: node.js, redis, publish-subscribe

I have the following scenario: 4 nodejs instances and a redis database.
I've created one channel and I have respectively one publisher and one subscriber. when i run one instance of the application it works. the subscriber subscribes to the channel. the publisher pushes to the channel and the subscriber consequently reads. no bad. but what happens when I have multiple instances? what I would like to do is that if the instance let's say `01` publish a message also the subscriber of the instance `02` must receive the message. does it will happen?

Comment: Yep you are correct. If all instances subscribed to same channel, they all will receive message.

Comment: @MykolaBorysyuk so no matter if they are physically located in a different position but if they share the same Redis and the same channel then it will work

Comment: Yep...Even from redis official. https://redis.io/commands/publish .. Integer reply: the number of clients that received the message. So publish in redis just tells of subscribers hey guys i got something new.